# Buttons Over Image Android

Tags: android, button, background

I am developing a feature for my app where the user can click on buttons that are placed within an image background. The problem: I need to place the buttons to a particular location within the image so it doesn't look displaced and works dynamically to different kind of devices' resolutions. Here's an image example:

[image]

I would like to place the buttons exactly where these rounded squares are. How can I be sure they will look exactly the same in different devices as well? I might need to place some text above each button. The buttons they have to be clickable and I have some animation over the buttons to allow the user to know when the button is being clicked. Any lead is much appreciated. Any feasible solution could be the accepted answer.

The game clash of clans have something similar:

[image]

This is exactly what I am trying to achieve!

Comment: And what is the problem/error?

Comment: That is a game. It's done completely differently. Games draw everything directly to the screen. It does not uses any of the standard android layouts. You can try to find some game engine like libGdx, but you won't do that with standard android layouts

Comment: I am not doing a game, just that kind of structure is interesting to me. But it looks that there is an image as background. The map is a image background and the buttons and dots probably drawn programatically but I can be wrong!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a hacked solution by using the percentages of the width and height of the device. It worked for tablets and 2 more different screen size devices.

```
    int w = front_layout.getWidth();
    int h = front_layout.getHeight();

    LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    int top = convert(h * 0.248f);
    int bottom = 0;
    int left = convert(w * 0.186f);
    int right = 0;

    params.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
    btn1.setLayoutParams(params);

private int convert(float value) {
    return (int) Math.ceil(value);
}
```

The only downside of it is that I have to find the exact percentages by try and error. A better solution will score my accepted answer!

Answer (score 0):

Since there are a lot of Android devices, in practice you can't show buttons exactly in all devices. You can use a RelativeLayout or a LinearLayout to assure that the top title will be above buttons

There will be a parent view with two children : One is for the title, and another is for all the buttons

Comment: I get the text how they will be placed after I know how to place the buttons, but how can I make sure I place the buttons in a position within the image? So that the button don't stay over the trailing (those dots)

Answer (score 0):

If you use a RelativeLayout, you could place the buttons at any point within the Image.

Just make sure that you use DP units of measurement and have size appropriate images for each density.

A short example:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <Button android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
    <Button android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />
    <Button android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: So I would be using try and error to find exactly where the buttons should be? By using margins wouldn't they get displaced differently over different phone resolution? They need to be exactly within those rounded squares because they have trailings between the buttons. Like a quest map

Comment: If you are using properly sized images scaled using density independent pixels, you can use DP to determine the x and y of your buttons.

Comment: What do you mean by properly sized imaged scaled using dp? You mean resizing the background image?

Comment: Usually you would set multiple images for the different screen densities. HDPI, XHDPI etc. However, that is mostly for icons. A large image would probably increase your APK size significantly. You could get away with one larger image, and let Android scale it down for you. Just set your layout_width and height correctly.